# How to create random pseudo samples from a non-stationary time series containing NaNs using Monte-Carlo method?

Tags: statistics, pseudo-random-generators, monte-carlo

I am looking for answers creating 500 samples of non-stationary Time series based on its probability distribution preferably using monte-carlo simulation. [DATA LINK](https://figshare.com/s/d0e30c3e80ecc41c42f9)

Secondly,  the most example available on any platform are considering normal distribution for creating the sample (like Monte Carlo) which sees fitting with the PDF of actual data, but I want check whether other distributions like lognormal and gamma is fitting better or not. Evaluating the best parametric distribution?

Looking forward to your answer or any direction you can give me towards the solution. I have attached my original data here. Any additional information i can share if required.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "creating samples...based on its probability distribution".  What is the input to the algorithm?  What is the desired output?  Please explain the task in more detail.  How is the probability distribution provided?  What prevents you from simply sampling from that distribution?

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for your reply. Actually i have seen in a paper that it's using Monte Carlo method to fill the data gaps (NaNs) in time series data. Where they have created pseudo-data using the monte-carlo method based on the probability distribution of data (this term they have mentioned). Then they done KS significe test to find the which distribution (normal, lognormal or gamma) best fits the data. Then based on this best fitted distribution they have filled the gaps in the time series. Now I guess my question add sense. Let me know if it's still unclear.